# Getting SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG on Apache2

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have a Apache2 webserver running and I created SSL certificate using sslforfree.com

Everytime when I try to reload a page I get a message "**SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**". I tried to disable firewall too.

This is my config of virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName www.dev.bellakabelky.sk
    Redirect / https://www.dev.bellakabelky.sk/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:433>
      ServerName www.bellakabelky.sk
      ServerAlias bellakabelky.sk
      ServerAlias dev.bellakabelky.sk
      DocumentRoot /srv/Cyclone3/!bellakabelky.sk/!www

      SSLEngine on
      SSLProtocol all
      SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/bellakabelky.crt
      SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/bellakabelky.key
      SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/bellakabelky_ca_bundle.crt

      <Directory /srv/Cyclone3/!bellakabelky.sk/!www>
              Options Indexes FollowSymlinks ExecCGI
              AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443 https
```

Port 443 is allowed, but I don't know where can be a problem.

Comment: Isn't there a typo: you wrote 433 rather than 443 for the port? Also see: https://serverfault.com/questions/892056/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-certbot

Comment: @ohmysql It can be typo, anyway thanks for hint :) I fixed it by creating new config file from scratch year ago :)