# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG certbot

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-16.04, certbot

I have the following setup:

- Apache 2.4
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- letsencrypt / certbot

Now, as soon as I enable the following .conf on the default server, all my configured top level domains receive a SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG error. **If I disable this config, everything works as expected.**

Because of this fact, I am sure, apache listens to the correct ports, to the correct IPs, and letsencrypt/certbot is correctly setup.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Require all denied
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Changing this to

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

has not solved the problem.

```
apache2ctl -S
```

shows the expected results, 001-default-ssl.conf and 001-default.conf are the defaults for port 80 and port 443.

```
openssl s_client -connect workingdomain.tld:443
```

prints:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
139991513372312:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1515852550
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Again, as soon as I disable this config, every domain configured with certbot/letsencrypt works as expected.

I don't get this, since I am basically blocking only the default server, all my other domains should be unaffected by this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to point to your SSL certificate -

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    DocumentRoot /var/www-example.com
    <directory /var/www-example.com>
        Options All
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    </directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to serve multiple domains, you can still do so at least for modern browsers that understand SNI/etc.

First, obtain separate letsencrypt certs for each domain.  If you have multple hostnames (ie, both `www.example.com` and `example.com`) they can share, as long as the actual domain is the same.

```
letsencrypt certonly -d example1.com -d www.example1.com -d mail.example1.com
letsencrypt certonly -d example2.com -d www.example2.com -d mail.example2.com
```

This will give you 2 sets of certs, under the `/etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAIN/` directories.

When you create your vhost configs, instead of specifying the `_default_:443` use the actual IP of the host and point to the appropriate certificate files.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.2:443>
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example1.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.com/privkey.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    DocumentRoot /var/www-example1.com
    <directory /var/www-example1.com>
        Options All
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    </directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example1.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example1.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 10.0.1.2:443>
    ServerName example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example2.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example2.com/privkey.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    DocumentRoot /var/www-example2.com
    <directory /var/www-example2.com>
        Options All
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
    </directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example2.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl-example2.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I don't collect form info, etc. on my sites, but I do want everything to run HTTPS so I set up vhost configs to redirect non-HTTPS requests to the HTTPS side, with a non-named catch-all that redirects to example1.com -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example1.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example1.com
  ServerAlias www.example1.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example1.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example2.com
  ServerAlias www.example2.com
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example2.com/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is still unclear to me, why this would affect my other domains? Could you please point me to some docs? My thoughts were: I wanted  the default site to act as a catchall for all requests to un-specified vhosts and 404 them (both http and https). This works for http, but for https I obviously need the vhost to point to the ssl certificate, as you have state above. I now realize, that I need to create a special purpose site to achieve this desired result, because for _default_ I cannot obtain a certificate by letsencrypt

Comment: @Michael Because you haven't specified a ServerName, etc.   I'll edit my post and add a LOT more detail on what works for me for serving multiple domains.

Comment: No, I think you understand my posting wrong. I do have 5 domains, which work perfectly fine using certbot / letsencrypt. But I wanted to change this behaviour: someone requests nonexistant.domain.tld :  the first vhost serves the request (it is used as fallback according to apache specs),  so I tried to create a default vhost and use this default vhost as a catchall and serve a 404 from there. If I deactive this default vhost, all domains are served perfectly fine :)